# Any Implications of Fermat's Last Theorem?

Tags: number-theory, proof-writing, diophantine-equations, alternative-proof

In our discourse FLT is Fermat's Last Theorem.
I am unaware of any theorems or conjectures that begin assuming FLT is true, or otherwise use FLT as a starting point or tool. The small amount of literature review I've done on this question reveals nothing.

My **question** is: Where can I find a work requiring FLT, or some useful implication of FLT? Even an implication of a polynomial inequality, that may not be FLT, may be a good answer to this question, as I'll likely try to use it to find something regarding FLT.

The following is **not acceptable** as an answer to this question:

$$ (a^{x_{1}}_{1} + b^{x_{1}}_{1} - c^{x_{1}}_{1}) \ldots (a^{x_{n}}_{n} + b^{x_{n}}_{n} - c^{x_{n}}_{n}) \not= 0 : x_{i} > 2 $$

and it's expansions imply (something trivial)

Another **acceptable answer** to this question would be a **proof requiring FLT to be false**.

Thanks and please let me know if I can ask this question in a way more fitting math.se (new user).

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Modularity_theorem

Comment: You may find it's a trivial consequence, but for $A \in \mathcal{M}_2(\mathbb{Q})$ a $2\times2$ matrix with rational coefficients, if $\operatorname{Tr}(A^n) = 1$ for some $n \ge 3$, then $A$ cannot have rational eigenvalues.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I don't know if this helps. But you can consider this for fun in the meantime while you search for something significant. More of a "nuking the mosquito"

To prove  $2^\frac{1}{n}$ is an irrational number when $n\ge3$.

$$2^\frac{1}{n}=\frac{p}{q}$$

$$p^n=q^n+q^n$$
which contradicts the $FLT$, therefore proving $2^\frac{1}{n}$ is indeed irrational.

On a side note, $FLT$ is not strong enough to prove the irrationality of $2^\frac{1}{n}$ for case $n=2$